# Passing array object in find Method (TypeORM)

Tags: typeorm

I am migrating the API to TypeORM from mongoose. I have an array(conversationIds) containing list of id to be searched from the Database and it should return me the available id. Below are the query which i have tried.

```
 const conversationMessagesWithDuplicates = await consversationRepository.createQueryBuilder("conversation").where("conversation.channel_message_ID = :channel_message_ID",{channel_message_ID : conversationIds}).getMany();
```

and also this one

```
const conversationMessagesWithDuplicates = await consversationRepository.find({channel_message_ID: conversationIds});
```

But i am getting below issue:

```
(node:11548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): QueryFailedError: Error: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

I have tried using entity Manger also but no success

```
const conversationMessagesWithDuplicates = await entityManager.query(`SELECT channel_message_ID FROM Conversation where channel_message_ID IN (conversationIds)`);
```

Below is the MoongoseAPI which is working fine:

```
Conversation.find( { channel_message_ID: { $in: conversationMessageIdArray } } ).exec(function(err, conversationMessagesDuplicatesArray) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```
const conversationMessagesWithDuplicates = await consversationRepository.createQueryBuilder("conversation").where("conversation.channel_message_ID IN (:conversationIds)", { conversationIds: conversationIds }).getMany();
```